# Iphone Music Metadata/Encoding data showing & hide

Tags: iphone, music, metadata, encoding, mp3

I play .mp3s via my iPhone Music application. However on this album, there is additional metadata / encoding data (unsure what the correct terminology is here) that is displayed below the Play and Shuffle buttons above the tracks. When I open `Get Info` on my computer's Music app, I can't find where this data is to remove it.

What is this and how do I hide it?

[image]

Comment: Get Info won't show it unless the drive is indexed by Spotlight. You need a meta editor [or iTunes etc] to change it. Same track on two drives… https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4eMH.png

Comment: Interesting @Tetsujin. However the text that is shown isn't on file's Get Info More Info section. https://imgur.com/a/l7UapDs